# Is there a way to validate DRL syntax in UI

Tags: drools

I have a UI to edit a DRL file. I was wondering is there a way to validate DRL file syntax in a UI?

I tried looking up for a DRL validator, I can't find one in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic validation (syntax, mostly) is done by compiling the rules.

More complicated validation is not possible because it requires understanding of the business domain.

The best way to test your validate your rules is to compile them and run tests against them, just like you would code.

See also: [Does drools have any validate utility that will scan a knowledge base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823358/does-drools-have-any-validate-utility-that-will-scan-a-knowledge-base/73830378#73830378)